# How can I alter the formatting of pandoc footnote marks?

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

Suppose I have the following markdown code, `test.md`:

```
This is a footnote mark.^[Which I would like to show up having brackets]
```

Using the following command, I then generate HTML:

```bash
$ pandoc --ascii test.md -o test.html
```

which gives me the following HTML:

```
<p>This is a footnote mark.<a href="#fn1" class="footnoteRef" id="fnref1"><sup>1</sup></a></p>
<div class="footnotes">
<hr />
<ol>
<li id="fn1"><p>Which I would like to show up having brackets<a href="#fnref1">&#8617;</a></p></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

The salient part of which shows up as:

This is a footnote mark.<sup>[1](http://example.com)</sup>

What I would like, is some way to have wikipedia-style superscript links, like so:

This is a footnote mark.<sup>[[1]](http://example.com)</sup>

Is there any way to do this? I can't figure it out, short of writing my own writer in lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS to style the generated HTML footnotes:

```css
.footnoteRef sup:before {
  content: '[';
}
.footnoteRef sup:after {
  content: ']';
}
```

```html
<p>This is a footnote mark.<a href="#fn1" class="footnoteRef" id="fnref1"><sup>1</sup></a></p>
```